# Windows 10 task manager shows 0% cpu under vmware

Tags: windows-10, vmware

I am running Windows 10 under VMWare Workstation Player 12.0.1 (Windows 10 is the guest, Ubuntu 15.10 is the host). When I run task-manager, it always shows that the cpu utilization is 0%, regardless of what the computer is actually doing. Each process in Task Manager also displays 0% CPU usage (even when building a large project under Visual Studio).

However, when I run "resource monitor", it clearly shows that there are processes that use much more than 0%.

**Edit**
Here are some screenshots, as requested:
[image: Task manager performance tab]
[image: Task manager processes]
[image: Resource monitor]

Comment: Can you include links to screen shots of the task manager? Also, it's a bit unclear where you are running task manager (in the host? in the guest?) and precisely what you're seeing.

Comment: I updated the question according to your comment.

Comment: have activated the option to visualize Perf counters in the VM options? if not, do so.

Comment: @Alex, anything new about this? I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uninstalling Hyper-V, which windows installed by default for some reason, solved this problem and many other problems I had with my virtual machine.

It can be uninstalled using the following steps:
1. Go to Control Panel --> Programs and Features
2. On the right side of the window, click on Turn Windows features on or off. A dialog box should open
3. Uncheck Hyper-V in the dialog box above and click OK

Comment: This is occurring on my Windows 10 Enterprise VM even though Hyper-V is not installed. Strangely it happened after I installed the Nvidia 368.81 drivers for my dual GeForce 980s.

Comment: That's unfortunate as Docker for Windows requires Hyper-V as far as I know. There's other things that require it as well, such as the Windows Phone emulators in the SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Your pictures looked exactly like mine, 0% CPU usage in Task Manager and Resource Monitor shows the CPU is always on max frequency. It was due to Hyper-V was installed in my VM. After uninstalling it, CPU usage display went back to normal. I didn't need Hyper-V in my VM so that was fine for me. I would like to know if there is another solution.

Comment: Please see my answer. I found a way to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling Hyper-V didn't work for me. I did the following:

- Shut down VM
- In the .vmx file, changed the following line:

  ```
  hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"
  ```

  to

  ```
  hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "TRUE"
  ```
- Restart VM

After that the CPU showed activity.